# property key in java properties file

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I need to set a java system property following IBM i JAVA rules. I will use the environment variable QIBM_RPG_JAVA_PROPERTIES to add/override the os400.stderr property.

I added ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_RPG_JAVA_PROPERTIES) +
VALUE('-Dos400.stderr=file:/QOpenSys/..../LogInfo/stderr.txt;') REPLACE(*YES)

It is in the context of calling HSSFR4 service program from Scott Klement, which starts JVM calling JNI interfase. The case is that adding this environment variable, java starts but fails generating a null pointer exception when calling JNI. If I comment the addenvvar statement, it works.

Besides, I'm receiving a java message JVAB55A without defined text currently: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1589487. It is a PTF for V7R3M0, even though we are at 7.2.

Have someone problems calling trace from java in IBM i? 
Have I forgotten something?

The corresponding configuration to get java trace is the following in my case:

```
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_RPG_JAVA_PROPERTIES) +                     
VALUE('-Dos400.stderr=file:/QOpenSys/..../LogInfo/stderr.txt;')
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_USE_DESCRIPTOR_STDIO) VALUE('Y')                                     
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_RPG_JAVA_EXCP_TRACE) VALUE('Y')
```

Comment: Your file path looks suspect to me.  Have you tried a different one, perhaps one not in /QOpenSys ?

Comment: (...) replaces here a proper name due to privacy concerns. It should be a valid name, according to IBM i rules. Anyway, I will try your suggestion pointing to current folder or something like that.

Comment: @jtaylor___ by the way, do you agree with such configuration to get the java trace? it is the first time I try it. But It is the way Programming Guide reccomend.

Comment: @jtaylor___ Perhaps you are right. First step done: created stderr file in root. Job ran and process worked as expected. Next step: enable trace. But it will be later today. Thanks! Which is the reason you not reccomended /QOpenSys path?

Comment: I've never tried a Java trace on IBMi.

Comment: Since you mention that you're trying to work with Excel files, I will mention that it is much easier to do that with Python. The first step to that, if you haven't already done so, is to install [yum](http://ibm.biz/ibmi-rpms).

Comment: @John , thanks, I will see its possibilities. I have worked with POI a lot, and I'm not sure if Python have all the same, and how it interacts through ILE. Same for pdf files.

Comment: Regarding message JVAB55A, Programmers Guide v7.2 says "If the options string is not valid, Java may reject one of the options. Message JVAB55A will appear in the
joblog indicating which option was not valid" related to java properties.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Only an error in declared path. Trace declared and used. With these three values the trace works. In my case, text file in EBCDIC, to be read in IBM i console. Surely it is possible to define UTF8 or ASCII outcome.

> ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_RPG_JAVA_PROPERTIES) +
>   VALUE('-Dos400.stderr=file:/QOpenSys/..../LogInfo/stderr.txt;')
>   ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_USE_DESCRIPTOR_STDIO) VALUE('Y')
>   ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_RPG_JAVA_EXCP_TRACE) VALUE('Y')